# Bash: overridding ls -la with ls -la | more (basic bash scripting problem)

Tags: unix, bash, script, ls, bashrc

Pretty new to bash scripting.  Trying to over ride the ls -la command to be: ls -la | more

(Seems more useful for me).

I added this to the end of my `.bashrc`.

```
154 # alias 'ls -la'='ls -la | more'
155         # this did not work because aliases
156         # are not allowed to have spaces in
157         # them. => have to make function:
158 ls() {
159         if [[ $@ == "-la" ]];
160         then
161                echo "test";
162                 command ls -la | more;
163         else
164                 command ls "$@";
165         fi;
166 }
```

But I get this error when I open a new terminal:

```
bash: /users/me/.bashrc: line 158: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /users/me/.bashrc: line 158: `ls() {'
```

When I add `function` before `ls() {` there are no complaints but there is no change to ls behavior.  Thanks.

### Update

Trying to narrow down the issue I did this:

```
159 ls() {
160         #if [[ $@ == "-la" ]];
161        # then
162                echo "test"
163 #               command ls -la | grep vim;
164         #else
165         #        command ls "$@";
166         #fi;
167 }
```

but I still get the same error.  I think that the main problem may be that it is in the bashrc file?

### Update

Strangely this works

```
159 function ls() {
160         #if [[ $@ == "-la" ]];
161        # then
162                echo "test"
163 #               command ls -la | grep vim;
164         #else
165         #        command ls "$@";
166         #fi;
167 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this on Bash-3.00.16 on Solaris 10 or Cygwin, but it looks like your bash is parsing line 158 as an invocation of the `ls` command, and not as a function definition.

The "function" prefix is optional, but if it makes your bash accept the definition, then it's a reasonable workaround.
It doesn't alter the meaning of the function in any way.

Incidentally, which OS and Bash version are you using ?

```
uname -a
bash --version
```

Comment: Running solaris 10 with the same bash as you.  My assumption was that it was just a mistake with the spaces or something like that.  Or maybe brackets.  Did you do a direct copy-paste of my code?  And it worked?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted it exactly into my .bashrc, removed line numbers, and no error was reported.

Comment: very strange..  No idea what the error suggests?

Comment: Ok that is mostly working now.  Did the if statement ever evaluate to true for you?  Ie: did `ls -la | more` ever execute?

Comment: HA!  I have an alias that takes ls and maps it to ls -F and that was messing things up.  Problem solved.

Comment: D'oh! The simplest solutions are always the best. Nice to know you got it fixed in the end.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this isn't exactly what you're asking about, but I mention it in case you've not thought about this sort of solution.  In my experience, the usual way to work around this is to make an alias without a space, e.g.:

```
alias llm="ls -la | more"
```

This is a lot quicker and easier than writing a script.  FWIW, I tested this on a FreeBSD 5.3 system running Bash 3.0 and it provided a listing run through more.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Thought about that but prefer the script solution.

Answer (score 1):

replace with:

```
 function ls
 {
         if [[ $@ == "-la" ]]
         then
                echo "test"
                /bin/ls -la | more
         else
                /bin/ls "$@"
         fi;     
}
```

Note: you'll need to reference the absolute path to the actual ls command inside the if or that'll reinvoke the same function and.... stackoverflow! :-)

EDIT: Yes, the command key word is a better way of preventing alias lookups.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is what the command keyword does?

Comment: Using the 'command' command (!) prevents the function/alias lookup.